# Eclipse imports these java projects incorrectly (main, site, test paradigm)

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, java-package

I encounter a few projects that have a set of folders in the src directory: main, site and test. A few levels under main eventually I encounter the `com.x.x.` package, all the files have package names that start with the `com` folder, not the `main` folder.

[image]

So when the project is imported into eclipse, whether as "existing project" or with "maven" , the result is that all the files in the project have errors because they can't find references to the other files in the package.

I'm wondering if this is a file structure paradigm that I just need to be aware of and import a certain way, or if I just need to restructure the projects

insight appreciated

Comment: What do you mean *specifically* when you say with "maven"? Where ever you're importing from, was the Eclipse .classpath file stored properly? Is there an up to date pom.xml? What's there to tell Eclipse how to do it correctly?

Comment: Could you take a look at the project settings? Which path is indicated for the sources?

Comment: @nintind, regarding maven I go to Import in eclipse, click on "Existing Maven Projects", I choose a folder which has a pom file in it, the pom file gets analyzed and I choose which project I want to import, and it then lists dependencies it will go install and that is when it finishes importing into my workspace. The package names do not match the folder structure. I get the pom.xml file by cloning from a git repository